# Unable to download the complete file using axios in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to download a pdf file which is of 60 mb from a server. When I am accessing the url directly in browser, I am able to download the complete file. 
But when I am trying to download the same file using axios in a react app i am able to completely download the file.

Each time the request stop after downoad 20MB or 2 mins. In dev console I can see ajax request is 200.

I have tried all configuration as suggested in axios github page.
Below the axios configuration which I am using,

```
this.axios.get(fileurl, {
           responseType: 'blob', // had to add this one here
           timeout: 999999999999999,
           maxContentLength: 2000000000,
           maxRedirects: 50,
           // headers: { Connection: 'keep-alive' },
           httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
           httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
       });
```

expected result:- should download the complete blob of size equal to the size of the file.

Comment: your best bet is to open the file to download in an iframe to leverage the default downloading that the browser provides rather than use an ajax request

Comment: What are you doing with the blob after the request? axios returns a promise...

Comment: I am trying to cache a 200 MB pdf file in indexdb and display the cached blob using PDF.js. 
I don't want to download this the already downloaded pdf again and again. 
Here is my code to store content in indexdb

 this.context.fileApi.downloadFile(filekey).then((response)=> {
                    console.log('response -------------------------------------------', response);
                    // @ts-ignore
                    addFilesToDb(filekey, response.data); //method to add files into indexdb
                  });

Unfortunately I don't have any other option left other.